# Forcing minimum height for tabularx row

Tags: tables, spacing, tabularx

I have a tabularx table using `multirow` and with all columns vertically centered. Here's the table:

```
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}
\def\tabularxcolumn#1{C{#1}}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C{3cm}|X|C{3cm}|N}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{logo}} &
\multirow{2}{*}{\Large{Title of this document}} &
    Doc.ref. &\\
\cline{3-3}
& & Revision &\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}%
```

I am looking for a way to force a minimum row height for a specific row in this table, but everything I tried didn't work for one reason or another.

- `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1cm}` breaks vertical alignment of the rightmost cells (they will not be vertically centered anymore)
- Adding extra space when breaking the rows, e.g. `&\\[1cm]` breaks vertical alignment of the first two cells (the ones using `\multirow`)
- Increasing the array stretch factor (e.g. `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}`) doesn't seem to play nice with vertical alignments (it seems to push the contents of the cells below the vertical center)

Update: Manually adjusting positions will not work as this is a template -- the actual document title is filled in later and may take one or two lines.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Couldn't one add a zero-width column, without border and a forced height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

REVISED solution, which eliminates the `multirow`, instead using a nested tabulars.  RE-REVISED to consolidate everything into `\makemytable{height}`, just to allow easier play-testing with various heights.

Here I just `\addstackgap[<length>]{object}` in order to add a vertical buffer above and below objects on that row.  Buffer size added depends *automatically* upon the height of the inserted image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,stackengine}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\newsavebox\customimg
\def\bufferA{.5\dimexpr\ht\customimg+\dp\customimg+1\normalbaselineskip}
\def\bufferB{.25\dimexpr\ht\customimg+\dp\customimg+.5\normalbaselineskip}
\def\setimgheight#1{\savebox\customimg{%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+.5\normalbaselineskip} %
  {\includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=#1]{example-image}}}
}
\def\makemytable#1{\setimgheight{#1}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C{3cm}|X|@{\hspace{0pt}}C{3cm}@{\hspace{0pt}}|N}
  \hline
  \usebox{\customimg} &
  \addstackgap[\bufferA]{\Large{Title of this document}} &
  \begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{0pt}}c@{\hspace{0pt}}}
      \addstackgap[\bufferB]{\makebox[3.0cm]{Doc.ref.}} \\
  \hline
   \addstackgap[\bufferB]{Revision} \\
  \end{tabular}&\\
  \hline
  \end{tabularx}\par\medskip
}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}
\def\tabularxcolumn#1{C{#1}}
\makemytable{1cm}
\makemytable{3cm}
\makemytable{5cm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But is it necessary to specify all of the gaps manually? The problem is that this is for a template; the "title of the document" will be filled in later, and it may take more than one row. I tried using addstackgap only to the "image" cell or to the "doc.ref" and "revision" cells and it still didn't work..

Comment: @Grodriguez you did not mention that the requirement is for a template, which implies no manual intervention.  My solution fails that test.  For that reason, I shall delete my answer.

Comment: Sorry. I did not realize that this would make a difference. I am still surprised there is no easy solution to what it would seem to be a very common problem..

Comment: @Grodriguez Please see revision.

Comment: Wow. Lots to study here :-)

Comment: @Grodriguez Sorry, I just slightly revised, when realizing that I had failed to apply the `\raisebox` to the image each of the three cases.  Thanks for the vote.

Comment: Great, thank you. BTW I think that with this solution you can skip the N column altogether in the col spec of the outermost table (that was a hack to fix alignment issues when using `&\\[1cm]`)